# Python split not recognizing hyphen

Tags: python

I imported a table with the years that each coach served as the football coach. Some of the years listed look like this: "1903–1910, 1917, 1919"

I am aiming for [1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 1908, 1909, 1910, 1917, 1919]

In my original DataFrame this list is an object.

I have tried:

`x = "1903–1910, 1917, 1919"`

`x[0].split('-')`

`re.split(r'\s|-', x[0])`

`x[0].replace('-', ' ').split(' ')`

I keep getting:

`['1903–1910']`

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't python finding the hyphen?

Comment: are the years a string?

Comment: In your second attempt, `x[0]` is a single character, so `x[0].split('-')` is the same as `'1'.split('-')`.  According to what you are aiming for, you should split first by comma, then split with hyphen within each result.

Comment: @SciProg it's in all of his attempts in some way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hyphen you see is not really a hyphen. It could be some other character, like an unicode en-dash which would look very similar.

Try to copy-paste the actual character into the split string.

Looking at the text you posted, here's the difference:

```
➜  ~ echo '1903–1910' | xxd
00000000: 3139 3033 e280 9331 3931 300a            1903...1910.
➜  ~ echo '1903-1910' | xxd
00000000: 3139 3033 2d31 3931 300a                 1903-1910.
```

The character in the first case is: https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Your character is not an hyfen, it's a dash:

```
>>> "–" == "-"
False
>>> x = "1903–1910, 1917, 1919"
>>> x.split("–")
['1903', '1910, 1917, 1919']
```

Comment: Thank you. Missing this is what I get for focusing on the forest instead of the trees.

Answer (score 0):

This works but not optimal

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
x = "1903–1910, 1917, 1919"
endash = '–'
years = x.split(', ')
new_list = []
for year in years:
    if endash in year:
        start, finish = year.split(endash)
        new_list.extend(range(int(start), int(finish)+1))
    else:
        new_list.append(int(year))
print new_list
```

Output: `[1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 1908, 1909, 1910, 1917, 1919]`

Comment: @Jackie could you try this solution  - it should solve your ultimate question

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just finished fixing my dataframe and your solution came in very useful.

Comment: Pleased to be helpful.